# Hibernate - delegate relations and their management to subclass in order to keep nice and tidy

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, relationship

Right now I have an User entity which contains its specific fields like id, name, password. The user is also an owner of Item entities, which are in Many-to-one and vice-versa relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    /* Id, name, password etc - strictly User specified */



    private List<Item> ownedItems;
    private List<Bike> ownedConsumables;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    public List<Item> getOwnedItems() {
        return ownedItems;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    public List<Consumable> getOwnedConsumables() {
        return ownedConsumables;
    }




    // a lot of methods to manage collections to keep one-to-many consistency 
    // which are not related to strictly to User entity
}
```

Due to many consistency problems related with such an organisation (bidirectional), I want manage them myself by properly implementing methods like addItem, removeItem etc. These are not directly related to User entity and I think I should move this responsibility to another class. I thought about:

```
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    /* Id, name, password etc - strictly User specified */

    private Inventory inventory;
}




public class Inventory {
    private User owner; // if needed - I think it will

    private List<Item> ownedItems;
    private List<Bike> ownedConsumables;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    public List<Item> getOwnedItems() {
        return ownedItems;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    public List<Consumable> getOwnedConsumables() {
        return ownedConsumables;
    }

    // a lot of methods to manage collections to keep one-to-many consistency 
}
```

Is this possible to do with Hibernate? How can I map everything to properly populate these collections?

Another idea is to create a class which will retrieve User object and manage collections, but this one requires ownedItems and ownedConsumables fields to be exposed via getters. Seems a worse one.

Comment: You can do that by annotating the class with @Embeddable, and the field inventory with @Embedded, but I don't really see the point. You'll just make the code and the queries more complex by adding `.inventory` everywhere.

Comment: Well, it's a pity I haven't tried it before posting.. I read about @Embeddable and didn't thought it can work in this case, but it seems it does. Wait a minute, I need to perform some tests more.

Comment: And talking about code practics, personally I don't like classes with tons of methods.. user.getInventory().addItem() looks a lot better than user.addItemToInventory(). Of course, chaining a lot method calls like a().b().c().d().e() is also a bad practice

Comment: Ok, everything seems to work as it should. Do you want to post an answer? @ Embeddable for class Inventory, @ Embedded for public Inventory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by annotating the class with `@Embeddable`, and the field `inventory` with `@Embedded`.

Comment: Futher investigation, to keep reference to User from it's parent, you can annotate reference field with @Parent - but this one makes embeddable class not reusable